# Excel sum values if exists in another column without vlookup

Tags: excel-formula

This is my data

```
A    B    C 
a    a   100    
b    r   200
c    m   300
d    b   400 
e    d   500
```

I want to sum C if B exists in A.

vlookup won't work because I cannot add a column (for reasons that cannot be changed). This must all be done from one cell. I cannot drag down a formula on any column.

I was thinking something like `sumifs(C:C,A:A,{if value for A exists in B:B}`

I'm not too familiar with arrays in Excel, but there must be a way to specify

```
if value for A exists in B:B
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way.  In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),0,1)
```

and copy down. *(column **D** marks the rows to add)*

Then in another cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:C*D:D)
```

or

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,D:D,1)
```

[image]

Comment: your sumproduct without the helper: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B5,A:A,0))*C1:C5)`

Comment: @ScottCraner  Consider posting it.

Answer (score 2):

A single formula using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B5,A:A,0)),C1:C5)
```

with SUMPRODUCT one should limit the size of the referenced data to that of the actual data to limit the unneeded iterations.

[image]